# Memory leak during JSON Initialisation using SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, instruments

First of all, I am new to instrument and memory graph. Was trying to check whether my app is having memory leak then I bump into this issue. It is a collection of class having MVVM architecture that does the functions below:

1. View Controller trigger a function in the View Model
2. View Model ask the networking class to retrieve JSON from web api
3. Networking class successfully retrieve data from the web api, it use SwiftyJson to convert the dictionary into JSON object and memory leak occur
4. The leak happen in the init function of SwiftyJSON aka JSON()/JSON.init()
5. The code base is a mixture of objective-c and swift but the classes that has memory leak are written in swift

---

I have done a little bit of research, below are my finding:

1. Create a new project and copy the classes and attempt to recreate the issue but no memory leak occur
2. This issue only occur when closure is called and return the result back to the caller
3. This leak also happen on other places that having similar code structure; Calling closure -> closure make an api call -> receive result -> convert into JSON -> Memory leak. Another case is getting remote config using Firebase SDK. In more detail, the function is FIRRemoteConfig.fetch

---

Enough of introduction, code and screenshot of memory graph and instrument as below, (The code class is pretty big so I only attach the most important part):

[image: Memory graph image]

[image: Instrument image]

View Controller Class

```
@objc final class HomeVC: UIViewController {
    internal lazy var viewModel = { return HomeVM() }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        initVM()
    }

    private func initVM() {
        viewModel.reloadPersonalization.addObserver(onChange: {[weak self] (reload) in
            if reload {
                self?.collectionView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: HomeSection.personalization.rawValue))
            }
        })
    }
}
```

View Model Class

```
import SwiftyJSON

class HomeVM {
    //MARK:- Observable

    let reloadPersonalization = Observable<Bool>(value: false)
    let isLoading = Observable<Bool>(value: false)

    //MARK:- Properties
    var personalizations = Personalization()

    //MARK:- Initialization
    init() {

    }

    //MARK:- Functions

    public func fetchPersonalization() {
        BaseApi.requestAPIService(apiService: MainMallService.showPersonalization, resultReceive: {

        }, success: {[weak self] (json) in
            self?.personalizations.updateProductList(json: json)
            self?.reloadPersonalization.value = true
            }, successWithError: {[weak self] (errorMsg) in
                self?.reloadPersonalization.value = false
        }, fail: {[weak self] (errorMsg) in
            self?.reloadPersonalization.value = false
        })

    }
}
```

Networking Class

```
import Moya
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

    class BaseApi {
        //MARK: Properties

        //MARK: Functions
        open class func requestAPIService(apiService: TargetType, resultReceive: @escaping () -> Void ,success: @escaping (_ jsonResponse: JSON) -> (), successWithError: @escaping (_ error: String) -> (), fail: @escaping (_ errorMsg: String) -> ()) {
            let provider = MoyaProvider<MultiTarget>(manager:NetworkManager.shared ,plugins: [NetworkLoggerPlugin(verbose: true)])
            let target = MultiTarget(apiService)

            provider.request(target) { result in
                resultReceive()

                switch result {
                case let .success(moyaResponse):
                    let data = moyaResponse.data
                    let json = JSON(data)
                    let apiStatus = ApiStatus.initWithJson(json: json["status"])

                    switch apiStatus.status {
                    case .Success:
                        if json["response"].exists() {
                            let jsonResponse = json["response"]
                            success(jsonResponse)
                        }

                    case .Failed:
                        successWithError(StringConst.Error.internalError)

                    case .Unkown:
                        fail(StringConst.Error.unknownError)
                    }

                case let .failure(error):
                    var errorMsg = ""

                    if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                        errorMsg = StringConst.Connection.timeout
                    } else if error._code == NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet {
                        errorMsg = StringConst.Connection.noConnection
                    } else {
                        errorMsg = StringConst.Error.unknownError
                    }

                    fail(errorMsg)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Memory leak occur on this line code, both memory graph and instrument is pointing to this line, again; Leak only occur when success block is called, other block like error and successWithError don't trigger the memory leak.

```
let json = JSON(data)
```

Appreciate your help !

Comment: Did you check with the library that you are using regarding any reported issues towards memory leaks that other users have encountered while integration.

Comment: @AkhileshSharma I do found a report on memory issue, it feels pretty similar but I was unable to reproduce the same result by creating a new project with the code above that is having the leak. 

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/967